# Exposing all RevenueCat PurchasesErrorCode codes in flutter

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I need to trap all of the listed PurchasesErrorCode error codes in my Flutter app so I can respond to them accordingly.

Currently I can only trap "userCancelled", for everything else I can only report the information returned in the standard PlatformException code, message and details properties, without knowing what they will contain.

```
try {

  // Code to make purchase..

} on PlatformException catch (e) {

  if (!(e.details as Map)["userCancelled"]) {

    // Here I need a comprehensive switch statement so I can
    // retry where appropriate/control what messages the user sees

    String reason = '';
    (e.details as Map).forEach((k,v) => reason += '$k => $v');
    showError(context, 'Error', '${e.code} : ${e.message}');

  } else {

    showError(context, 'Purchase Cancelled', 'Your purchase was not completed, you have not been charged.');

  }
}
```

These codes are exposed in IOS/Swift and Android/Kotlin but I can't get them in Flutter/Dart - what am I missing?

Comment: may be other excepts are not PlatformException  ? use try and catch and see

Comment: Thanks, but the RevenueCat documentation says that all exceptions will be thrown as PlatformException. And I can't use try..catch to examine all possible RevenueCat exceptions since I can't trigger them.

Comment: It seems to me that what you really want to know is what are the error codes held in RevenueCat's `PlatformException`s. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but exposed as enums or equivalent in Dart so I don't have to hard-code them in and risk breaking in the future. As a temporary solution I could build my own enums (or even parse the description), but this isn't ideal. The APIs for other languages expose them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I developed the RevenueCat Flutter plugin and I created an issue on GitHub some time ago to track this (https://github.com/RevenueCat/purchases-flutter/issues/3). I am sorry there is some room for improvement in our Flutter error handling.

When we send the platform exceptions we pass the error code as an String:

`result.error(error.getCode().ordinal() + "", error.getMessage(), userInfoMap);`

Too bad we can't just pass an int as the first parameter and we have to pass a String, I guess we could pass it in the `userInfoMap`. But for now, since we are not providing the enum with the error codes yet, you would have to do something like this in your code:

```dart
enum PurchasesErrorCode {
  UnknownError,
  PurchaseCancelledError,
  StoreProblemError,
  PurchaseNotAllowedError,
  PurchaseInvalidError,
  ProductNotAvailableForPurchaseError,
  ProductAlreadyPurchasedError,
  ReceiptAlreadyInUseError,
  InvalidReceiptError,
  MissingReceiptFileError,
  NetworkError,
  InvalidCredentialsError,
  UnexpectedBackendResponseError,
  ReceiptInUseByOtherSubscriberError,
  InvalidAppUserIdError,
  OperationAlreadyInProgressError,
  UnknownBackendError,
  InsufficientPermissionsError
}

try {
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  PurchasesErrorCode errorCode = PurchasesErrorCode.values[int.parse(e.code)];
  switch (errorCode) {
    case PurchasesErrorCode.UnknownError:
    case PurchasesErrorCode.PurchaseCancelledError:
    case PurchasesErrorCode.StoreProblemError:
    // Add rest of cases
  }
}
```

When you do `e.details`, you also get access to a `readableErrorCode` containing the name of the error code; and an `underlyingErrorMessage`, that can hopefully help you debug any issue.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The issue mentioned on the previous answer was solved, after version 1.0.0 you can handle like this:

```dart
try {
    PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo = await Purchases.purchasePackage(package);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
    var errorCode = PurchasesErrorHelper.getErrorCode(e);

    if (errorCode == PurchasesErrorCode.purchaseCancelledError) {
      print("User cancelled");
    } else if (errorCode == PurchasesErrorCode.purchaseNotAllowedError) {
      print("User not allowed to purchase");
    }
}
```